# SwifUI loop over strings to add item

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, swiftui

I got an array of strings, doing a `VStack` to make them vertically,
I'm trying for each item to add an image  in the beginning of the first `Char`, my code is working,

the only problem is the checkmark image is not aligned.

it should be simple and as the code is executed, the image should be in the beginning of the string, what's the problem?

```
     VStack(alignment: .leading){
                ForEach(features, id:\.self){ description in
                    HStack{
                        GCheckmark()
                        Text(description).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with alignment, like

```
HStack(alignment: .top) {       // << here !!
    GCheckmark()
    Text(description).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .gistFont(.body)
}
```